# How to remove duplicate value and group data?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, duplicates, grouping

I have list in which i want to remove duplicate value(Day) which is Monday in image. Currently data is showing like this here is my image, so basically how i want in display that for Monday it should be grouping like

```
Monday --- 09:00:00 - 16:00:00
           18:00:00 - 21:00:00
Tuesday   18:00:00 - 21:00:00
```

[image]

i have tried to used distinct linq function but it remove whole row. I need to remove only one value which show in image

```
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Setings.AccessToken);

                    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://172.16.4.212:51583/api/GetConsultantTimeTable/"+ consultantid);


                    consultantTimeTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<procGetConsultantTimetableAPI_Result>>(json);
                    List<procGetConsultantTimetableAPI_Result> trends = new List<procGetConsultantTimetableAPI_Result>(consultantTimeTable);


                    MyListView.ItemsSource = trends;
```

Comment: where is an image?? kindly provide what values are in list and what is expected...

Comment: just added image also edited my question

Comment: can u send me code how to add in my code?